# document.createElement() style images does not work

Tags: javascript

Check the code below. In the function called `createElement` I am taking random image from `images` array but the problem is I am getting single image animated.

My main goal is to make animation with random images from those 4 images, not single image like now. How can I fix that?

```js
var maxElements = 20;
var duration = 4000;
var toAnimate = [];
var radius = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight ? window.innerWidth : window.innerHeight;
var distance = radius / 4 <= 250 ? 250 : radius / 4;

//var images = ['#FF1461', '#18FF92', '#5A87FF', '#FBF38C'];
var images = ['https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg', 'https://image.ibb.co/bDCBOU/img5.jpg', 'https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg', 'https://image.ibb.co/bDCBOU/img5.jpg'];

console.log(images);

var createElements = (function() {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < maxElements; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.classList.add('particule');
    el.style.images = images[anime.random(0, 4)];
    toAnimate.push(el);
    fragment.appendChild(el);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(fragment);
})();

var animate = function(el, i) {
  var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 3;
  anime({
    targets: el,
    translateX: [0, Math.cos(angle) * distance],
    translateY: [0, Math.sin(angle) * distance],
    scale: [{
        value: [0, .1],
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'easeOutBack'
      },
      {
        value: 0,
        duration: 4000,
        delay: duration - 8000,
        easing: 'easeInBack'
      }
    ],
    offset: (duration / maxElements) * i,
    duration: duration,
    easing: 'easeOutSine',
    loop: true
  });
}

toAnimate.forEach(animate);
```

```css
.particule {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 70rem;
  margin: -.5rem 0 0 -.5rem;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>

<div class="particule">
  <img id="img-1" src="">
  <img id="img-2" src="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to set the `backgroundImage` property of `styles`.

I've updated the random selection part to avoid attempting to access indices of the `images` index which are not present.

```js
var maxElements = 20;
var duration = 4000;
var toAnimate = [];
var radius = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight ? window.innerWidth : window.innerHeight;
var distance = radius / 4 <= 250 ? 250 : radius / 4;

//var images = ['#FF1461', '#18FF92', '#5A87FF', '#FBF38C'];
var images = ['https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg', 'https://image.ibb.co/bDCBOU/img5.jpg', 'https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg', 'https://image.ibb.co/bDCBOU/img5.jpg'];

console.log(images);

var createElements = (function() {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < maxElements; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.classList.add('particule');
    
    var selectedImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); 
    
    el.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[selectedImage]}')`; // template literal
    toAnimate.push(el);
    fragment.appendChild(el);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(fragment);
})();

var animate = function(el, i) {
  var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 3;
  anime({
    targets: el,
    translateX: [0, Math.cos(angle) * distance],
    translateY: [0, Math.sin(angle) * distance],
    scale: [{
        value: [0, .1],
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'easeOutBack'
      },
      {
        value: 0,
        duration: 4000,
        delay: duration - 8000,
        easing: 'easeInBack'
      }
    ],
    offset: (duration / maxElements) * i,
    duration: duration,
    easing: 'easeOutSine',
    loop: true
  });
}

toAnimate.forEach(animate);
```

```css
.particule {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 70rem;
  margin: -.5rem 0 0 -.5rem;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gZfv09/img2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>

<div class="particule">
  <img id="img-1" src="">
  <img id="img-2" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I feel that I did; I explained that it was selecting wrong indices, and then corrected it. I didn't want to go into how the `anime.random` function was working because it is better to me to do this with `Math.random` instead.

Comment: What I meant was I initially voted this down because I did not see the need for another random function until I realised that the one used by OP actually did not work. When I figured that out, I removed the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
el.style.images = images[anime.random(0, 4)];
```

would need to be valid - it is not now. There is no ".images" style attribute

Also anime.random(0,4) does not return a value between 0 and 3 which is what you want

This works

```
el.style.backgroundImage = "url("+rnd(images)+")";
```

adding

```
var rnd = function(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}
```

```js
var maxElements = 20;
var duration = 4000;
var toAnimate = [];
var radius = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight ? window.innerWidth : window.innerHeight;
var distance = radius / 4 <= 250 ? 250 : radius / 4;

var images = ['https://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-640-7.jpg', 'https://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-640-6.jpg', 'https://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-640-9.jpg', 'https://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-640-1.jpg'];

var rnd = function(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

var createElements = (function() {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < maxElements; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.classList.add('particule');
    el.style.backgroundImage = "url("+rnd(images)+")";
    toAnimate.push(el);
    fragment.appendChild(el);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(fragment);
})();

var animate = function(el, i) {
  var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 3;
  anime({
    targets: el,
    translateX: [0, Math.cos(angle) * distance],
    translateY: [0, Math.sin(angle) * distance],
    scale: [{
        value: [0, .1],
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'easeOutBack'
      },
      {
        value: 0,
        duration: 4000,
        delay: duration - 8000,
        easing: 'easeInBack'
      }
    ],
    offset: (duration / maxElements) * i,
    duration: duration,
    easing: 'easeOutSine',
    loop: true
  });
}

toAnimate.forEach(animate);
```

```css
.particule {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 70rem;
  margin: -.5rem 0 0 -.5rem;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  transform: scale(0);
  /* background-image: url('https://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-640-7.jpg'); */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>

<div class="particule">
  <img id="img-1" src="">
  <img id="img-2" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was because your original answer occasionally gave divs with no image at all because of how the random selection was working. I'm not sure who downvoted this though, so I can't really say.